# Trying to sent e-mail in utf-8 format, however Content-Type is still set to iso-8859-1

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm going mad, this is the code I'm using to send an e-mail utf-8 encoded, however when I receive the mail, it uses utf-8 characters but headers are set as iso-8859-1 characters.

1. Is it a problem from PHPMailer?
2. Could this be a problem from the smtp server which is "overriding" those headers?
3. Any solution available?

   Connect();

     $mail=new PHPMailer();
     $mail->Charset = $ENCODING_TYPE;
     $mail->ContentType="text/html; charset=".$ENCODING_TYPE;
     $mail->IsSMTP();
     $mail->Host=SMTP_HOST;

     $mail->From=SITE_MAIL;
     $mail->FromName=mb_convert_encoding(SITE_MAIL_NAME, $ENCODING_TYPE, "auto");
     $mail->Subject=html_entity_decode(stripslashes($title), ENT_COMPAT, $ENCODING_TYPE);
     $body=''. stripslashes($title).'';
     $body.="
   ".'

   ### '.html_entity_decode(stripslashes($title), ENT_COMPAT, $ENCODING_TYPE).'

   '.mb_convert_encoding(stripslashes($mail_body), $ENCODING_TYPE, "auto")."
   *".html_entity_decode(stripslashes($author), ENT_COMPAT, $ENCODING_TYPE)."*";
     $body.="
   -----------------------------
   "."FooterText"."
   Tel. - Fax 06.32.16.059

   ";

     $mail->IsHTML(true);
     $mail->MsgHTML($body);
     $mail->AltBody="Usare un visualizzatore di html-mail per visualizzare questa e-mail";
     // $lemails=$tsql->QueryAssoc("SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE '1' AND prog_per_email='1' AND email!='' ORDER BY cognome ASC");
     $lemails=Array(
       Array(
         "email" => "my-email@test.com",
         "cognome" => "Me",
         "nome" => "Ye"
       )
     );
     $mails_sent  = 0;
     $mails_total = 0;
     foreach ($lemails as $to) {
       $mail->AddAddress($to["email"],$to["cognome"]." ".$to["nome"]);
       if ($mail->Send())
         ++$mails_sent;
       ++$mails_total;
       $mail->ClearAddresses();
     }

     return "Inoltrate ".$mails_sent." su ".$mails_total." contatti trovati";
   }
   ?>

I don't know why code shows html and has all those formatting problems, here you can see the pastie version:

http://pastie.org/5533692

Please, note that I've written this code when I where 16 years old, and I would like to avoid a complete rewrite (well, this function can be rewritten).

Comment: try $mail->CharSet=$ENCODING_TYPE; instead of $mail->Charset

Comment: "what the ...", thanks, I can't believe I lost 2 hours just for this... I think it's my fault because I didn't have error reporting on. If you put it as an answer I can mark it.

Comment: i had the same issue sometime back :) thnks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `$mail->CharSet=$ENCODING_TYPE;` instead of `$mail->Charset=$ENCODING_TYPE;`